# Self-hosted collaboration like Trello

Tags: collaboration, self-hosted

Due to privacy and data security guidelines I need to switch my team collaboration over to something self-hosted. Can anyone recommend the right tool for a scenario like this:

- Self hosted, open-source preferred, but not mandatory
- Free, or paid-once preferred
- Kanban preferred, eventually with agile/classic list option
- PHP+SQL, no server framework like sandstorm

I have looked at:

- Trello, perfect, but not self-hosted
- Wekan (aka Libreboard), perfect, but sandstormed, email integration missing
- Taiga, super good, didnt find info on email integration

Comment: Could you please list which team collaboration features you need? For example, for those that don’t know Trello, and because you probably don’t need *all* of Trello’s features.

Comment: Can you explain "`sandstormed`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up looking at [Taiga](https://taiga.io/) and [92five](http://92fiveapp.com/), both lacking some features. After two days of research I recommend myself (and to you so you don't have to redo all the research): [**JetBrains YouTrack**](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) or [The Bug Genie](http://www.thebuggenie.com/), from which I prefer the former.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot, some of which:

- wekan - couldn't install it. huge problems with installation scripts and dependencies. the dev team ignore it blaming the "build environment"
- restya - after waiting an hour for installation script to run, it looked great.. then with no use whatsoever, started redirecting each page to the logout page across every browser. shame.
- orangescrumm - untrustworthy developers. will not use.
- kanboard - initially looks horrid, but simple, fast, very extensible, well written and with a bit of css, looks magic. Lots of plugins exist for it and if it doesn't you can write you own using the 'hooks' system.

Subsequently, I recommend Kanboard - kanboard.net